# Solution of an ODE (Ordinary Differential Equation)

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, functions, solution-verification

I don't seem to understand this paragraph statement from our learning material regarding the idea of a solution Φ of an ordinary differential equation.

### Paragraph statement:

"It is mentioned earlier that a solution Φ of an ODE is differentiable, thus it is continuous on its interval I of definition. It means that there may be a difference between the graph of a function Φ and the graph of a solution Φ which can also be stated as, the domain of a function Φ is not necessarily the same as the domain of the solution Φ."

### My question & interpretation:

From the definition of a solution of an ODE (this is from the same material), "a solution of an nth-order ordinary differential equation is a function Φ that possesses at least n derivatives." For this, I thought that the solution Φ is the function Φ of a given ODE, but the paragraph statement makes it look like they differ from each other and I want to know how and why? What are your thoughts about this? Thank you!

-currently advance studying Elementary Differential Equations

Comment: The only association I see is that the domain of an ODE is always an open interval. A solution method for certain classes of ODE can produce a function that has poles or other singularities, for solutions you would have to reduce the domain to intervals without such.

Comment: Thank you for this information!